# why recode values returning an error in RStudio

Tags: syntax-error, recode

Having an issue with a simple recode.

```
baseline <- baseline %>%
  mutate(userid = recode(userid, 1000 = '2000'))
```

returns the following error

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
"#baseline <- baseline %>%
    mutate(userid = recode(userid, 1000 ="
```

Comment: I have attempted, replace, rename and recode without success.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected my earlier attempt to the following.

```
 baseline <- baseline %>%
   mutate(userid = replace(userid, userid == 1000, 2000)
```

This worked.